# How to Access Ember Object Scope on Object Method

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Conceptually, I'd love to be able to define methods in Ember Objects that have access to the object's `this` without having to declare them as computed properties or observers. Currently, it's possible to do this:

```
var TestObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    testFunc: function(self, arg1, arg2) {
        self.set("testProperty1", arg1);
        self.set("testProperty2", arg2);
    },
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        this.get("testFunc")(self, "test1", "test2");
    }
});
```

In the above example, I have emulated access to the object's `this` property by passing it to the function in the argument `self`. However, that's kind of hacky. Is there any way to create a method on an Ember Object that has full access to the `this` property, like this:

```
var TestObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    testFunc: function(arg1, arg2) {
        this.set("testProperty1", arg1);
        this.set("testProperty2", arg2);
    },
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        this.get("testFunc")("test1", "test2");
    }
});
```

I realize that this might not be idiomatic in Ember, but I often find that I want to be able to write functions that are reusable multiple times within an Ember Object, necessitating the ability to create methods. If it doesn't exist, maybe a syntax like this could work:

```
var TestObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    testFunc: function(arg1, arg2) {
        this.set("testProperty1", arg1);
        this.set("testProperty2", arg2);
    }.method(),
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        this.call("testFunc", "test1", "test2");
    }
});
```

For the `this.call` function, the first argument is the name of the method that should be called, and the rest of the arguments are the arguments to be passed to the method. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered using 'call' or 'bind' in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Yes, however neither of those really solves the problem of having to specify the context of the function `this` manually. My proposed syntax would mean `this` was automatically bound to `testFunc`, without having to specify in every function call to `testFunc`.